# dplyr::mutate_at for changing prefixes?

Tags: r

I've got a data frame (df) with three variables, two of which have the prefix abc and one with the prefix def.

I'd like to use **dplyr()** to change the prefix of the variables starting with abc, so that they instead have the prefix new.

The problems that my current code's not working and I don't understand why.

Thanks!

Starting point (df):

```
df <- data.frame(abc_question1_F1_Q1=c(1,2,1,2),abc_question_F1_Q2=c(1,2,1,2),def_question1_F1_Q3=c(1,2,1,2))
```

Desired outcome (dfgoal):

```
df <- data.frame(new_question1_F1_Q1=c(1,2,1,2),new_question_F1_Q2=c(1,2,1,2),def_question1_F1_Q3=c(1,2,1,2))
```

Current code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(contains("abc_")), function(x){gsub("abc_", "new_", x)})
```

Comment: Try `names(df) <- sub("abc", "new", names(df))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to use `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
   rename_all(funs(sub("^abc", "new", .)))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
names(df) <- sub("^abc", "new", names(df))
```